# How to format currency by CultureInfo in DevExpress XtraCharts?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am creating charts programmatically in a manner similiar to [this example](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument6244) on the DevExpress website.  I see where you can identify series data to be formatted as currency, but the reporting tool is globally based and needs to be able to format the various chart labels using a passed in currency.

Here is an example of code used to generate a typical SeriesView:

```
private void FormatBarSeries (SideBySideBarSeriesView bar)
{
    bar.AxisY.NumericOptions.Format = NumericFormat.Currency;
    bar.AxisY.NumericOptions.Precision = 0;
    bar.AxisY.Title.Text = "Sample Bar";
    bar.AxisY.Title.Font = new Font(GetChartFontFamily(), 10.0f, FontStyle.Regular);
    bar.AxisY.Title.Visible = true;
    bar.AxisY.Tickmarks.Visible = false;
    bar.AxisY.Tickmarks.MinorVisible = false;
    bar.AxisX.Tickmarks.MinorVisible = false;
}
```

I cannot seem to find any manner of defining the culture for the specific chart.  Each report may contain multiple charts, but all the charts on a report would be the same currency format.

Can this perhaps be set at the report level and have all charts inherit it?  Or how can I set this on a chart by chart basis?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, as demonstrated [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q398404):

You have to hook into a CustomDrawAxisLabel event:

```
Chart.CustomDrawAxisLabel += Chart_CustomDrawAxisLabel;
```

where you can override the code with a function like this:

```
void Chart_CustomDrawAxisLabel (object sender, CustomDrawAxisLabelEventArgs e)
  {
    AxisBase axis = e.Item.Axis;
    if(axis.NumericOptions.Format == NumericFormat.Currency)
      {
        decimal value = 0.00M;
        e.Item.Text = decimal.TryParse(e.Item.AxisValue.ToString(),
                                        out value)
                         ? value.ToString("C0", _culture)
                         : e.Item.AxisValue.ToString();
      }
  }
```

using a culture variable defined elsewhere in the class.